# Qual a diferença entre usar SaveChanges() apenas uma vez após adicionar dados por meio de um foreach e usar dentro do foreach?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Eu estou inserindo uma média de 50 mil registros no banco de dados via Entity Framework. E me veio uma dúvida referente as seguintes colocações de código: na primeira (1) colocação, utilizo um `foreach` criando os objetos com seus dados e os adiciono (`contexto.addToTabela`), usando o `SaveChanges()` fora do `foreach`, no final de todo o processo, sendo utilizado apenas uma vez. A segunda (2) colocação seria utilizando o `SaveChanges()` dentro do foreach, ou seja, a cada objeto adicionado há um `commit`. Qual a diferença entre as duas situações?

exemplo em código:

situação 1:

```
using (entities contexto = new entities())
{
    foreach (var item in lista)
    {
        ...
        contexto.AddToTabela(item);
    }

    contexto.SaveChanges();
}
```

situação 2:

```
using (entities contexto = new entities())
{
    foreach (var item in lista)
    {
        ...
        contexto.AddToTabela(item);
        contexto.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Já pensou em fazer uma inserção em massa?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Na lógica:
Na situação 1 você está colocando tudo em uma única transação, se uma linha der erro, o rollback será sobre tudo. Já na situação 2, ele vai salvar até a linha que der erro, sem um tratamento try catch específico ele vai parar o foreach.

Na performance:
Na situação 1 ele vai empilhar tudo na memória, os 50 mil registro e enviar de uma única vez. Dependendo do caso, pode deixar o processo um pouco lento.
Na situação 2 ele recebe o dado e já envia, há muitas conexões com o servidor de BD. Arrumar uma terceira situação onde ele faz um SaveChanges a cada 100 itens pode ter uma performance melhor que as duas situações. Não pesa muito a memória e também não faz tantas requisições únicas com o BD.

Se você puder usar o Entity Framework 6, use o método AddRange:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.addrange%28v=vs.113%29.aspx